# Youtube Gaming Live stream status

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

How I can get Youtube Gaming live stream status, if its live or offline?
And then make it to text e.g Channel is offline or Channel is online. Its not my channel.

Comment: Hey, did my answer help you?  Feel free to follow up with any questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve information on another channel's broadcast, you have to use the [`Search/list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list) endpoint.

`part -> snippet`

`channelId` -> `[channelId of the channel/user with the live event]`

`eventType -> live`

`type -> video` (required when setting `eventType` to `live`)

```
HTTP GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId={channelId}&eventType=live&type=video&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

If the user is not currently streaming, the GET request will return zero items.